# Flutter testing WillPopScope with back button

Tags: flutter, testing, flutter-test

On my Home widget, when user taps system back button, It shows by a WillPopScope a confirmation dialog widget.
I want to test this dialog but I cant figure it out how to press the back button on a test file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem but i had no back button in my app. I wanted to test the android system back button. This is how I did it. Maybe it's helpful for people who run into the same problem as me.

```
testWidgets("test onWillPop",(WidgetTester tester) async {
    bool willPopCalled = false;
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () async {
              willPopCalled = true;
              return false;
            },
            child: Container(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    final dynamic widgetsAppState = tester.state(find.byType(WidgetsApp));
    await widgetsAppState.didPopRoute();
    await tester.pump();

    expect(willPopCalled, true);
});
```

Inspired by: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/test/material/will_pop_test.dart

Comment: Why not test this `expect(await widgetsAppState.didPopRoute(), isTrue);` as well?

Comment: It's a case of personal preference, personally I never test the functionality of the Flutter framework itself. The code snippet I wrote is only an example of how you can trigger the back button. In normal cases you have your widget defined within the source project and you expect something to happen when the back button is pressed. I would only assert the suspected outcome.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you cannot access `Navigator` in the test. So my solution is to include `BackButton` somewhere in the pumped widget and to pop the page like this:

```
await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      child: BackButton(),
    ),
  ),
));

...

await tester.pageBack();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I cant figure it out how to press the back button on a test file.

This will help you to see back button on appbar(top part of app). It will allow you to see back button via appbar

```
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: _onWillPop,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Title"),
      centerTitle: true,
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
        onPressed: () => _onWillPop(),
      ),
    ),
    body: Body(),
  ),
);
```

_onWillPop will be your "confirmation dialog widget" for your question.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, because I wanted to kill 2 birds with 1 stone, and actually ensure the back button (which is generated by default in the AppBar, not added by me) was appearing too;

```
final backButton = find.byTooltip('Back');
await tester.tap(backButton);
```

Then obviously just pumpAndSettle, and test your other screen.